# Regex affecting all URLs other than a specific domain in Yahoo Pipes

Tags: regex, twitter, yahoo-pipes

While working with a Twitter Search RSS feed in Yahoo Pipes, I'm trying to clean up long Twitter links and replace them with their shortened versions. To that effect I want to match any link text that is NOT on a Twitter domain. Usually, those are t.co links.

Here's an example of what I want to do:

turn

`<a href="http://t.co/AiyTQKaAoU">http://www.denverpost.com/environment/ci_26064841/colorado-coal-mine-mulls-appeal-after-federal-court ...</a>`

into

`<a href="http://t.co/AiyTQKaAoU">http://t.co/AiyTQKaAoU</a>`

My regex started as `<a .*?href=['""](.+?)['""].*?>(.+?)</a>` which matched all links.

Then I tried `<a .*?href=['""]!(www\.twitter\.com\/?)['""].*?>(.+?)</a>` to remove twitter.com from the results, but it's not working. What I doing wrong?

P.S. I need to not touch Twitter links because that will mess up all '@' and '#' links.

Addition: Solution by @Avinash-Raj works in the demo but not inside the Yahoo Pipe. Anyone familiar with regex inside Yahoo Pipes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Yahoo Pipes, something like this should do:

- pattern: `href="(http://t.co[^"]*)"[^>]*>http://[^<]*`
- replacement: `href="$1">$1`

Here's a [demo pipe](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.edit?_id=bfd051a9e018a65f91a3dd9439bd7b1c), and [here's another, based on your pipe](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=487b666057ecefc66ff8b8eba148f8b7).

PS: you know you can put multiple regex replacements in a single **Regex** operator. It's easier to read that way.

Comment: Thanks, @janos! However, it doesn't work in my particular pipe. Could you adapt it to parse the following source code: `Rolling Coal: Conservatives ‘screw’ Obama by modifying trucks to spew toxic black smoke <a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="http://t.co/BWxgcA8j3h">http://www.rawstory.com/rs/2014/07/07/rolling-coal-conservatives-screw-obama-by-modifying-trucks-to-spew-toxic-black-smoke/&nbsp;…</a>`

Comment: Can you share the link to your pipe? It will be easier for me to clone that and fix there

Comment: [The pipe is here:](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.edit?_id=a6cf64cd4fd0c07b5536863e12250f25) -- top right corner. Thanks!

Comment: Janos, was there anything else you needed from me to finish this up?

Comment: @Bogdan I updated the pattern in my post, and created a demo based on your pipe. Let me know if you still need help.

Comment: it works, thank you very much. As for the multiple replacements inside one regex operator module, thanks for that as well :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try the below regex to capture the value of href attribute and used it again  in the replacement part to modify the `<a>` tag. It must works on the lines which don't have the string `twitter.com`

```
^(?:(?!.*twitter\.com.*$))(<a href=\"([^\"]*)\">).*?(<\/a>)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/hU4eV0/3)

Comment: But that will affect ALL links, including the ones I don't want to modify... I need to figure out how to check for the domain name and only act if it's NOT twitter.com. Any more ideas?

Comment: so you wamt to modify like above only if there is no twitter.com present in that line.

Comment: It works in your demo, but does not work inside the Yahoo Pipe. Can you help with that as well? You can clone it from here: [link](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=a6cf64cd4fd0c07b5536863e12250f25) -- the regex you suggested is in the top right node.